# Retrieve on which key an action is binded (without the InputSystem)

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 2019, I want to retrieve, in a script, on which key an action is configured, Fire1 or jump for example, to display the possible actions in the game.
The only answer I've found uses the UnityEngine.InputSystem, but it doesn't seem to be available yet in the version I'm using (2019.2.14f1).

Currently, my inputs are set following the `Edit -> Project Settings -> Input`.

Comment: so there are 2 input systems the "old" one and a new one you have to install the package for and its been around for a few years.. so unless you have an incredibly out dated unity, you likely just havent installed it.  However, there are many examples on using the old one.. so you should be able to find them if you look